# Copy value from specific cell in google spreadsheet to another via button

Tags: google-apps-script, copy-paste

On the click on a Button I want a function to be triggered that copies the value from **Sheet1!A6** to **Sheet2!A6**. [(see template)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AveLEDuTZv0vdGYyWl9tLUZ5YmFKUE9Za2VqUVRVcEE&usp=sharing) ! 
What do I have to add to this to make it work?

```
function CopyPasteA6() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');            

   sheet.getRange('A6').value
    ???
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this, it's probably the simplest way to do it.

```
function CopyPasteA6() {
   var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');            
   var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');            
   sheet1.getRange('A6').copyTo(sheet2.getRange('A6'))
}
```

then insert a drawing or an image in your sheet and assign the function to this image.

[image]

**EDIT following your comment :** this script copies to the next sheet if it exist. you'll have to put a button on each sheet though.... I'd suggest to use a menu instead that will be acessible from anywhere in the spreadsheet.

Note that 'A6' or "A6" are just the same ;-)

```
function CopyPasteA6() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
   var sheetidx = sheet.getIndex()-1 ;
   var nextSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[sheetidx+1];

   sheet.getRange('A6').copyTo(nextSheet.getRange('A6'))
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I just had to replace ('A6') with ("A6"), then it worked perfectly! Also I added   `sheet1.getRange("A6").copyTo(sheet2.getRange("A6"),{contentsOnly:true})` to keep the formating

Comment: Just one last question: Is there also a way to select the copying sheet as the "previous" sheet in the spreadsheet? (The reason is that I need this function 12 times, and it should always copy from the previous A6 to the next A6...   (Sheet1!A6 -> Sheet2A6, Sheet2!A6 -> Sheet3!A6 etc...) I read there is something like sheetsbyID ?

Comment: Hm, this I did not understand :(  I didnt even manage to select a sheet by ID... this  `var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetId('3');` gave me an error`

Comment: Please red thoroughlythe code I wrote, there is no getSheetId()... the provided code works, I've tested it.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my stupidity! (btw, since I want to always copy from the previous sheet to the active sheet, I just needed to change to: `var previousSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[sheetidx-1];` again thanks, it all works perfectly now.